# Sending data through my api doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm making a simple todo app. I'm using angular for the frontend and nodejs for the backend. After doing some debugging I now can post data to my mongodb database using Postman though when I do it on my website a new object is being created on the database but without the values that I've given to the object.

This is my model and how I connect to the database:

```
var mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tododb');
var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', {
name: String });
```

and here is how I handle the request:

```
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res){
  Todo.create({name: req.body.name, checked: false},
  function(err, todo){
    if(err) res.send(err);
    Todo.find(function(err, todos){
      if(err) res.send(err);
      res.json(todos);
    });
  });
});
```

I'm also using bodyparser to handle the data:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

This is my function on the frontend (AngularJS):

```
$scope.formData = {};    
$scope.addTodo = function() {
    $http.post('/api/todos', $scope.formData)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.todos = data;
            $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
    };
```

Another problem is that the `$scope.formData = {}` doesn't clear the input field.

And lastly this is the part of my html file that displays the todos:

```
  <h1>Things you have to do</h1>
  <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
    <p id="todobox"> {{ todo.name }} </p>
  </li>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="I need to do..." ng-model="newTodo">
    <button ng-click="addTodo()">Add</button>
  </form>
```

This is the result I get when I visit `localhost:300/api/todos`

```
[{"_id":"57275afef11dc77b17a90eda","__v":0},

{"_id":"57275b5ef11dc77b17a90edb","name":"test from postman","__v":0}]
```

The first one was created from my input box by clicking the add button, the second one was created by sending a post request with Postman and telling it what the name value is.

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED] Have you tried changing your input and making sure you use a `.`:

JS

```
$scope.info = {todos:[], newPost:{name:''}};    
$scope.addTodo = function() {
  $http.post('/api/todos', $scope.info.newPost)
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.info.todos = data;
        $scope.info.newPost = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
        console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
};
```

HTML

```
  <h1>Things you have to do</h1>
  <li ng-repeat="todo in info.todos">
    <p id="todobox"> {{ todo.name }} </p>
  </li>
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="I need to do..." ng-model="info.newPost">
    <button ng-click="addTodo()">Add</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Nope, I still get the same thing, though Ι changed the value to formData.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have too many variables to store the data. You expect it to be stored in `formData`, but it's actually stored in `newTodo`.

Your HTML should look like:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="I need to do..." ng-model="formData.name">
  <button ng-click="addTodo()">Add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: hmm, the name value still doesn't register to the database

Comment: Can you debug the Node server and verify that the data is transferred in the request body?

Comment: Did a simple console.log(req.body.name) and I get undefined, seems that this is the problem

Comment: So let's go one step back. Can you do `console.log($scope.formData)` as the first line of `addTodo` (before calling `$http`)

Comment: I've fixed the issue. It was a problem with bodyParser. Thank you for the help